# Taking photos and video with CameraUI: MediaPromise.file is null on iOS

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, camera

I'm developing a AIR App that asks the user to take a photo or video and upload it to a server.
Everything was OK with Android, but I found out that `MediaPromise.file` was `null` on iOS.

I don't need/want to manipulate the image/video at all, I just need to get this `File`/`FileReference` and upload it to the server.

My problem is that, as iOS doesn't give me a `File` from the `MediaPromise`, I don't have anything to upload.

Googling around I found out how to, asynchronously, load the the data (with the `Loader.loadFilePromise()`) from the promise, but I don't know how to encode it as a video when I call `camera.launch(MediaType.VIDEO);` (where `camera` is a `CameraUI` instance).

I'm handling the `camera.launch(MediaType.IMAGE);` call just fine already, but I really want to get the file directly from the OS, if it is possible, so I don't need to encode it myself.

To sum it up, I need to upload the photo/video the user just took with the `CameraUI` API on the iOS.
How can I do this?

**note**: I can provide some code if needed...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be what you're looking for...[AIR for iOS - Taking & Uploading Photos](http://www.fizixstudios.com/labs/do/view/id/air-ios-camera-and-uploading-photos)